# Migration of ASP.NET Core 5 to ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I implemented my project in a modular way and also from the onion architecture, as you can see in the code, in ASP.NET Core 5. I did the following to introduce a module to the core in startup. My question: I want to use ASP.NET Core 6. How should I define this block module in `Program.cs`?

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     var connectionstring = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SeikoDB");
     BlogManagementBootstrapper.Configure(services,connectionstring);
}
```

Class `BlogManagementBootstrapper`:

```
public class BlogManagementBootstrapper
{
    public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IBlogQuery,BlogQuery>();
    } 
}
```

Comment: [Does the official doc useful to you ?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

First Part .Net Core 6 Configuration in program.cs

```
builder.services.AddDbContext<YourContextName>(x=>
{
   x.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SeikoDB"));
});
```

Second Part .Net Core 6 Configuration in program.cs

```
builder.services.AddTransient<IBlogQuery,BlogQuery>();
```